# T-SQL set trailing numbers to zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a stored procedure on SQL Server 2014.

I have a variable:

```
DECLARE @VersionNumber DECIMAL(18,1);
```

This VersionNumber can have values such as 1.0 or 1.4.

In my logic, I increase the number *+0.1* if there is a *minor change* and *+1* if there is a *major change*.

If there is a major change though, I want to reset the trailing numbers to 0.

**Example: Version 1.4 should become 2.0 after a major change**

My current query looks like this:

```
IF @IsMajor = 'true'
BEGIN
    SELECT @VersionNumber = COALESCE(1 + MAX([VersionNumber]), 1)
    FROM [MySchema].[Project]
END
IF @IsMajor = 'false'
BEGIN
    SELECT @VersionNumber = COALESCE(0.1 + MAX([VersionNumber]), 1)
    FROM [MySchema].[Project]
END
```

Do you know how to reset the trailing number to 0 on a decimal number?

Thank you!

Comment: So what does version 1.9 become after a minor change? Obsolete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`FLOOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/floor-transact-sql)

```
IF @IsMajor = 'true'
BEGIN
    SELECT @VersionNumber = FLOOR(COALESCE(1 + MAX([VersionNumber]), 1))
    FROM [MySchema].[Project]
END
IF @IsMajor = 'false'
BEGIN
    SELECT @VersionNumber = COALESCE(0.1 + MAX([VersionNumber]), 1)
    FROM [MySchema].[Project]
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first cast `MAX(VersionNumber)` to an `int`. This will cut off the decimal digits. If you convert it back to a `decimal(18,1)` you can add 1:

```
SELECT COALESCE(1 + CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 1), CONVERT(INT, MAX([VersionNumber]))), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

or ceiling

```
IF @IsMajor = 'true'
BEGIN
    SELECT @VersionNumber = ceiling(MAX([VersionNumber])+.1)
    FROM [MySchema].[Project]
```